# RMagick's color_histogram results in something unlike a hash

Tags: ruby, hash, imagemagick, histogram, rmagick

I've been playing around with RMagick's [color_histogram](http://www.simplesystems.org/RMagick/doc/image1.html#color_histogram) method to get a histogram of colors in a quantized 8-bit image.

However, while I'm supposed to get a hash returned from this method, I get something kind of wonky. The output from IRB upon inspecting the "hash" looks like this:

`=> {red=1907, green=1893, blue=2716, opacity=0=>25801, red=21141, green=14902, blue=13109, opacity=0=>3744, red=35552, green=15344, blue=8229, opacity=0=>1427, red=48734, green=19120, blue=8539, opacity=0=>1280, red=62091, green=22662, blue=8733, opacity=0=>75158, red=57917, green=33805, blue=24932, opacity=0=>275, red=47046, green=39657, blue=37365, opacity=0=>1873, red=64379, green=64336, blue=64330, opacity=0=>10442}`

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: That's not a valid hash. I'd say the output is just garbled for some reason, the data structure (hash) is probably still working properly. Did you try `color_histogram.class`..what does that say? Also note that each key in the hash is one **pixel**, so for any moderate size image the hash will be humongous.

Comment: @Casper I did try `color_histogram.class` and it output `Hash`. I reduced the image to 8 colors so there should only be 8 keys in the hash.

Comment: Hmm..ok. What about `color_histogram.keys.first`..what does that look like? And `color_histogram.keys.first.class`. I think the hash might be ok after all, the keys just represent color values (red, green, blue + opacity).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading the documentation for `color_histogram` you find the explanation:

> **Each key in the hash is a Pixel** representing a color that appears in the image. The value associated with the key is the number of times that color appears in the image.

Looking further you find that [Pixel is a class](http://www.simplesystems.org/RMagick/doc/struct.html#Pixel). So that explains the weird looking output. Each key in the hash is of class `Pixel`. So when you see:

```
{ red=1907, green=1893, blue=2716, opacity=0 => 25801 }
```

What you are really looking at is:

```
{ Pixel => histogram_count }
```

Or:

```
{ Pixel(red=1907, green=1893, blue=2716, opacity=0) => 25801 }
```

The `irb` printout just compressed the output a bit so it was hard to read before you realize what is going on.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much. It would help to know a bit more Ruby to really know what to do with this, but glad the structure's apparent now.